# How to derive the distribution of 1 - X

Tags: cumulative-distribution-function, beta-distribution

Suppose X is a random variable from the Beta(0.5, 1) density. I want to derive the distribution of Y = 1 − X

My attempt:

$F_{1-X}(\alpha)= P(1-X \leq \alpha) = P(1-\alpha \leq X) = P(X\geq 1-\alpha) =1-F_X(1-\alpha)$

I'm stuck on how to get from this to $Y \sim Beta(1,.5)$